# How to show a value which is not bound by the CategoryPath or ValuePath inside the Telerik's RadCartesianChart's Tooltip?

Tags: c#, mvvm, telerik

I'm working with a telerik RadCartesianChart. And I'm supposed to show a tooltip which conveys the information about the series inide the chart (such as the date, the value, the title of the series). I was able to show the date and value which were already bound in the CategoryPath and the ValuePath of the chart respectively. But I have no clue how to show the title of the series which belongs to the same data source but not bound by either the CategoryPath or the ValuePath.
Below is what I have done so far.

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="chart" Margin="0,10,0,36" Width="auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
        <telerik:ChartTooltipBehavior HorizontalOffset="-11" VerticalOffset="-50" />
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.TooltipTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" CornerRadius="3">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.TooltipTemplate>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis
            x:Name="datetimeAxis"                                            
        LabelFitMode="MultiLine"
        LabelFormat="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.LabelFormat}"
        LabelInterval="1"
        LabelOffset="0"
        LabelRotationAngle="270"
        LabelStyle="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}"
        LastLabelVisibility="Visible"
        LineDashArray="1 1"
        LineStroke="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}"
        LineThickness="1"
        MajorTickInterval="1"
        MajorTickLength="1"
        PlotMode="OnTicks"
        SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep"
        TickThickness="5"
        ZIndex="0" Height="5" />
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <telerik:LinearAxis Foreground="White" LastLabelVisibility="Visible" HorizontalLocation="Right"/>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
        <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="Y" />
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="AxisLineStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:LinearAxis}" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ColorName, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NVarToBrushConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColorName, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NVarToBrushConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ellipseTemplate">
            <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PaletteConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="rectangleTemplate">
            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PaletteConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="triangleTemplate">
            <Polygon Points="10,5 5,10 15,10 10,3" Stroke="GreenYellow" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PaletteConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!--<DataTemplate x:Key="+Template">
                <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PaletteConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="xTemplate">
                <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PaletteConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>-->
        <Style TargetType="telerik:LineSeries" BasedOn="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle}">
            <Setter Property="LegendSettings" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ChartViewLegendSettingsValueConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowLabels" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding ColorName, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NVarToBrushConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAxis">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <telerik:LinearAxis ElementBrush="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.LineSeriesColor}" HorizontalLocation="Left"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="PointTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:BarSeries"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BarSeriesStyle}">
            <Setter Property="CombineMode" Value="Stack"/>
            <Setter Property="LegendSettings" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ChartViewLegendSettingsValueConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowLabels" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAxis">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <telerik:LinearAxis ElementBrush="Gray" HorizontalLocation="Right"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="PointTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PaletteConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:PointSeries" BasedOn="{StaticResource PointSeriesStyle}">
            <Setter Property="LegendSettings" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ChartViewLegendSettingsValueConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowLabels" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAxis">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <telerik:LinearAxis ElementBrush="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.PointSeriesColor}" HorizontalLocation="Left" />
                    <!--Style="{DynamicResource AxisLineStyle}"-->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="PointTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Resources>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.SeriesProvider>
        <telerik:ChartSeriesProvider Source="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.GraphsToDisplay, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <telerik:ChartSeriesProvider.SeriesDescriptors>
                <telerik:CategoricalSeriesDescriptor x:Name="CatSeries" CategoryPath="TimeStampX" ValuePath="ValueY" ItemsSourcePath="Data" TypePath="SerieType"/>
            </telerik:ChartSeriesProvider.SeriesDescriptors>
        </telerik:ChartSeriesProvider>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.SeriesProvider>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement, you can use the `Presenter` property of the `DataPoint` object.

The `DataPoint` object is the data context passed to the `TooltipTemplate`.

The `Presenter` is a property of `DataPoint` which holds a reference to the series object that hosts the concrete data point.

```
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.TooltipTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Presenter.DataContext.MySeriesNameProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.TooltipTemplate>
```

You can read a bit more about the DataPoint class in the [RadChartView documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/getting-started/data-point).

Comment: Hi, Martin. Thanks for your answer. I already got it working. I added another property to the data source object and changed the binding path like this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.LegendName}"/>`.

Comment: Great to hear this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding a new property called `LegendName` to the data source object. And changed the binding path like this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.LegendName}"/>`. Not sure whether this is the proper way but it's working as intended.